How can I view a complete package list for each release of Ubuntu?
Im looking for a complete list of all packages by release of Ubuntu version. https://packages.ubuntu.com/ allows me to view all packages in a release which is nice, but what about each individual release as Im not seeing a difference between a release and an update release.
For example, the previous link provides the option to browse the packages in the jammy 22.04 release, which includes the package ghostscript (9.55.0~dfsg1-0ubuntu5.9), while the jammy-updates release has the same version of ghostscript included. Meanwhile, my install of 22.04.01 has ghostscript (9.55.0~dfsg1-0ubuntu5.1), so at what point was this upgraded? 22.04.04 is the latest so are the jammy and jammy-updates both referring to the latest 22.04.04?
Where can I view the package listing for the 22.04.01 vs 22.04.04 releases?

This also resembles an XY Question. If your question is really "when was package ABC upgraded?" you don't need two multi-thousand line lists of packages. You could simply grep your apt log. But it's unclear why the resulting date would be a useful answer to you. A more useful question might be "why isn't my system using the latest ghostscript package in the jammy repos?"

There is no such "update release" set of patched software, etc.  The point releases of Ubuntu rely on respins of the ISO with updated installer, and updated packages for the installer media.
If you are already on Ubuntu, and applying updates normally from the -updates and -security pockets, you're already up to date, and you will automatically be on the point release when it's released.
With regards to ghostscript it sounds like you have not run or installed your updates since you installed your system, which is why you see different version strings.  If you run a standard update process (sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade) while connected to the Internet to upgrade the packages on your system your 22.04 machine will automatically get all updates since the last run of updates and you'll have the updated package versions for ghostscript and other packages.  But there is no real "upgrade release" like Windows does.
